# How to listen to Talkback's focus-change in Android?

Tags: android, accessibility, talkback

I'm working on improving the accessibility within my app.

I have pretty complicated layout with cards. Each card has some clickable objects inside it, but it also has the global click-listener.

When I enable Talkback, select the card (not something inside it!), double-clicking (to open the card), the card gets the touch-event in the middle of the card.
As a result, nested object got click event and react respectively.

The question is how to determine, which item is in TalkBack's focus (green-rectangle-thing for me)? The idea is to disable inside touch-listeners, if card itself is in focus.

API level I want to support is **16** (Android 4.1+)

Thanks!

Comment: What's your min target SDK? On API 21+ you can check View.isAccessibilityFocused().

Comment: Unfortunately, I'm aiming to support all devices starting API 16. Though, it's still very useful comment, thank you!

Answer (score 5):

I think what would work best for you, is to override the accessibility delegate of layout view, listening for accessibility focus events.  When focus is added to a card, remove listeners, when focus leaves your cards re attach  your listeners.  Attach this delegate to your layout view, and you should be able to watch as various views within your layout obtain and give up accessibility focus.

```
class MyAccessibilityDelegate extends View.AccessibilityDelegate {

    @Override
    public boolean onRequestSendAccessibilityEvent(ViewGroup viewGroup, View child, AccessibilityEvent event) {

        if (event.getEventType() == AccessibilityEvent.TYPE_VIEW_ACCESSIBILITY_FOCUSED) {
            //Do stuff in here!  Maybe also do different stuff when focus is cleared!
        }

        return super.onRequestSendAccessibilityEvent(viewGroup, child, event);
    }


}
```

The apis for this were added in API level 14 so you should be good to go!

Comment: In my case I'm getting TYPE_VIEW_HOVER_ENTER when tapping on a list row.